# Layout bug: comments overflow into RHS pane

Tags: bug, status-deferred, design, comment, css

In [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8501/best-cities-for-mathematical-study) the comments are displaying so wide that they overwrite all the text in the rightmost pane (which includes "visit meta", "nn people chatting", etc). The bug exists in both IE and Chrome.

Comment: (btw, no-repro on Firefox.)

Comment: (no-repro on Chrome 8-dev/Mac, too)

Comment: I too can no longer reproduce it - even in the same browser sessions.

Comment: @Bill: Maybe because I have deleted that comment.

Comment: @Kenny: That probably explains why it's no longer reproducible. So the bug seems to be triggered only when a long unbreakable line appears in a comment, e.g. a long url?

Comment: @Jeff: "status-norepro" is incorrect. It *is* reproducible, but Kenny deleted the comment that triggers it. That is the source of the above "no-repro" comments.

Comment: @Jeff: no-repro on Firefox, but definitely repro on IE-8.

Comment: Was just about the report this. (Chrome 15.0.874.121 Win7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been reported a lot of times, e.g.

- [Long comments can break layout](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66430/long-comments-can-break-layout)
- [Bug Report: The Pollyanna Effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41068/bug-report-the-pollyanna-effect)
- [Comments not getting line broken for some strings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65983/comments-not-getting-line-broken-for-some-strings)

etc. The current resolution is `[status-we-dont-know-how-to-fix]`, [quoting @Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5460/post-overflow/42662#42662),

> Near as I can tell, **there is no way to get this to work on comments** because they are variable width. That is, the actual comment size depends on whether or not the comment vote UI controls are present (fex, on your own comment, you don't have controls, if you're not logged in there are no controls, etc), and if the comment has say 100 upvotes that's wider still.

and

> I'm not willing to make comments fixed size at the moment. I thought about checking server side by looping through the string and forcing spaces every (n) characters if there aren't any just to prevent griefing.

Comment: correct, there is no fix in HTML as currently known. The fix is to edit or delete the comment.